# How to give specific constraints to the grid items

Tags: flutter

**Problem**: The grid item (skill card) does not take a specified height and width. instead, takes the height of the gridview (SizeBox(height:200))/crossAxisCount.

I want to give a specific width and height to the gridview. but it does not work.
I want the `SkillCard()` to take the specified height and width. How do I do that?

```
               SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      child: GridView.custom(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          // mainAxisExtent: 100,
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                        ),
                        childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return const SkillCard(
                              skill: 'Flutter',
                              percent: 75,
                              icon: flutterLogo,
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                           
                            );
                          },
                          childCount: 9, // Total number of items
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: give width of size box as skill card width * crossAxisCount

Comment: @Rahul Does't work

Comment: "How to give specific constraints to the grid items" see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount/SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount.html and it's `childAspectRatio` property

Answer (score 0):

- try this code to solve your issues.

  ```
      SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: GridView.custom(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
    ),
    childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 100, 
          width: 100,  
          child: SkillCard(
            skill: 'Flutter',
            percent: 75,
            icon: flutterLogo,
            height: 20,
            width: 20,
          ),
        );
      },
      childCount: 9, 
    ),
   ),
  ),
  ```

Comment: Tried.does not work

Comment: please explain in details what's your issue.?

Comment: The grid item (skill card) does not take a specified height and width. instead, takes the height of the gridview (SizeBox(height:200))/crossAxisCount.

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: GridView.custom(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: (20 / 20),
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    ),
    childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SkillCard(
          skill: 'Flutter',
          percent: 75,
          icon: flutterLogo,
          height: 20,
          width: 20,
        );
      },
      childCount: 9,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: no brother, does not work

Comment: @user8 and what do you expect? if you use `crossAxisCount: 3` then you will have 3 columns with the same width, do you want different widths or what?

Comment: @pskink yes, I want diffrent width and height as specified in the skillcard()

Comment: @user8 wrap your `SkillCard` with `Center` for example but honestly it will look ugly as you will have a lot of empty spaces

Comment: The skillcard should take a specified height and width for that. not resize based on the crossAxisCount